# Не удается установить MySQL на Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

Пытаюсь настроить рабочее окружение Ubuntu на VirtualBox. Столкнулся с проблемой установки MySql. Через терминал прописываю

`$ sudo apt-get clean` 
`$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server`

Ответ:

> Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
>           Построение дерева зависимостей
>           Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
>           Уже установлен пакет mysql-server самой новой версии (5.7.23-0ubuntu0.18.04.1).
>           Обновлено 0 пакетов, установлено 0 новых пакетов

Логично, так как до этого уже пытася провести установку, но при вызове `$mysql`

Получал ответ

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

При первично установке я получил ошибку в терминале в GUI ошибку:

> Automatic maintenance of MySQL server daemon disabled Packaging maintainer scripts detected a case that it does not know how to handle and cannot continue configuring MySQL. Automatic management of your MySQL installation has been disabled to allow other packaging tasks

Что это вобще такой за демон автоматического обслуживания и как его включить?
В файле $ sudo nano /etc/mysql/FROZEN он мне как раз предлагает на него переключиться. Что делаю не так, подскажите?

Так же пробовал 
~$ mysql_secure_installation

> Securing the MySQL server deployment.
>
> Enter password for user root:  Error: Can't connect to local MySQL
>   server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Здесь обнаружил что в /var/run нет каталога /mysqld

Попробовал создать:
~$ sudo mkdir /var/run/mysqld
~$ sudo mkfifo /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
~$ sudo chown -R mysql /var/run/mysqld
~$ mysql

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (13)

При проверке статуса  через sudo systemctl status mysql.service
получаю вот это:

> mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
>         ● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
>          Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
>          Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2018-08-16 16:30:08 MSK; 3min 8s ago
>         Process: 4676 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
>       mysql.service: Control process exited, code=exited statu
>       mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
>       Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
>       mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling re
>       mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is
>       Stopped MySQL Community Server.
>       mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
>       mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
>       Failed to start MySQL Community Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не уверен что я до конца понял проблему, но офф. статья все решила. 
https://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/mysql
Сам над собой поржал.

Answer (score 1):

посмотри есть ли в `/etc/mysql/` этот файлик FROZEN.

если есть - перемести или удали и переустанови mysql-server.

у самого такая же ошибка, попробовал сделать так - все заработало.

ps за последствия ответственности не несу.